# Submit button works in Chrome but not in Firefox when echoed in Php

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I created a login and register button assign link to them, but they didn't work in Firefox nor in IE but fine in Chrome and Safari. The code is put within echo in php so that they only show when user is not logged in.

```
<form>
<?php if(!$videosite->CheckLogin())
{
echo('<a href="Login.php">
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="g-button g-button-green" value="Sign in"   width= 100% /></a>
<a href="register.php">
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="g-button g-button-red" value="Create an Account" width=100% /></a>');
}
else
{
?>
<a href="#"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="g-button g-button-submit" value="     <?php echo($videosite->UserFullName()); ?>" width=100% /></a>
<a href="logout.php"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="g-button g-button-white"    value="Logout" width=100% /></a>;
<?php 
}
?>
</form>
```

What happen in Chrome and Safari when user click the button they took to the login or register page according to button they press. In case of Firefox and IE, they didn't go to the required page, rather this is shown in url- ***"http://localhost/project/?submit=Sign+in"*** in case of login!, similar for signup.

What's the problem with it?
Why it not working in IE and Firefox? How to correct it?

Comment: On first glance, the code you've posted contains nothing that is browser specific. Looks like you're hiding away the point that actually triggers this so please do some basic debugging first.

Comment: why do you need the wrapper `<a>`-s around your `<submit>`-s?

Comment: @hakre yes i understand that there is nothing that is browser specific but still i got the error???

Comment: @ZoltanToth the `<a>` is used for link only

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is a **form element**, yet you are using it outside of form.

It should look like this:

```
<form action="login.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

OR, just use the `a` element to make a link and style it the way you want...

```
<a href="login.php" class="..." style="...">Sign in</a>
```

Comment: Then just don't wrap the `input` with a link... And if you want multiple `submit` buttons to point to different `actions` (login.php vs register.php) inside one form, then you can use javascript events on the buttons to change behavior, for example, add `onclick="document.location.href='register.php';return false;"` to register button

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`, if you want the user to take to login/signup screen or simply remove input element and just use plain text.

If element is currenly in a form, remove the anchor tag around element.
If you use, type="submit", form which wraps this element will gets submitted.

Comment: When `type="button"` is used the **"http://localhost/project/?submit=Sign+in"** changes to **http://localhost/project/** and still not functional

Answer (score 0):

You Code :-

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="g-button g-button-green" value="Sign in"   width= 100% />;
```

change that to :-

```
<input type ="button" class="g-button g-button-green" value="Sign in" width= 100% />
```

OR else just change to :-

```
<a href="Login.php"> LOGIN </a>
```

Comment: Changing the type of button not helpfull